# Adding figures on first page of documentclass article

Tags: floats, margins, article

I'm using the default article documentclass for a document that is just supposed to hold the accompanying figures for a paper.
This is what I'm doing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {path} }
\geometry

\begin{document}\vspace{-10ex}
\title{My title}
\author{Author 1        \and
        Author 2 \and
        Author 3 }
\maketitle  
\\
\\

\center

\section*{Accompanying Figures}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=7cm]{twoapproaches.pdf}
\caption{Two approaches to mutli-class vehicle classification}
\label{fig:1}      
\end{figure}\\  
% Few more figures
\end{document}
```

On the first page I have to put a rather long diagram, but it always shows up on the second page. I thought maybe it just doesn't fit. I reduced the image size but it only comes on the first page if I make it really small. I have an entirely empty first page! How can I fix this? How can I edit the margins/font size of the default article document class?

Comment: Kick out the double backslashes, use `vspace` instead. The command is called `\centering`, don't use the `figure` environment. If you need a caption, use `captionof{figure}{Your caption}` form package `capt-of`. A less forcing approach would be adding placement option `b`. But i fear, that there is not enough available space on the page.

Comment: I doubt that the figures are allowed on the same page as title.  Use `captionof` as suggested by Johannes.

Comment: `\geometry` isn't defined here `\center` shouldn't be used as a command and most `\\ ` need to be removed (especially the one after `\end{figure}` You get multiple errros from this as posted

Comment: I bet it's the \maketitle.  It does odd things.

Comment: @Mark: Boromir of LOTR would say: In `\maketitle`, there's evil, that does not sleep ;-)

Comment: that's going a bit far... it probably sleeps sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion is to use `float` package and `H` position, forcing the figure to stay in its position in the text. Just add `\usepackage{float}` to your preamble and start your figure as `\begin{figure}[H]`.